# Is a MySQL SELECT query faster with as much as possible keys in a table?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is a difference in perfonance if you have a query that SELECTS on 4 keys or 5 keys.

If yes, why is this? What tests can I run for this?

For example

```
SELECT name FROM table where country='ES' AND page='ABC' AND color='BLUE' AND hobby='PAINTING' AND status='SINGLE'
```

versus

```
SELECT name FROM table where country='ES' AND page='ABC' AND color='BLUE' AND hobby='PAINTING'
```

Comment: I suspect that there's no part of this problem that you couldn't test for yourself faster than ask us!

Comment: Show your indexes.  What is the size of your `table`?

Comment: It probably depends on that data. Use `explain select ...` to look at it yourself

Comment: You may want to ask this question in [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I highly recommend reading through http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Does it matter which query is faster, when they return different result sets?

Answer (score 0):

Other things being equal testing for 5 columns (using `AND`) should be marginally slower. For example:

- If both queries perform a full index scan (assuming there's no secondary index suitable for the query), then testing the condition with five columns could be a bit slower, but probably not really perceptible. This is because the engine would need to evaluate the extra predicate on all the rows of the table/primary index.
- On the flip side, if both queries use an index (primary or secondary) then the performance could be almost identical, since it would require pretty much a single index seek.

Comment: What about `INDEX(status,country,page,color,hobby)`?

Answer (score 0):

In generic, I prefer you to do the following rather than indexing [ofcourse must have index]

Since this is the AND operator, whatever condition not satisfied it will move off to next level [ here 5 `and` operator, if the 1st `AND`condition didn't satisfy, then it will quit from the query]

So apart from `indexing` need to check the records which shouldn't go for a full table scan. In your case, if the status should be `single/married`.  This should be in the last of your `AND` operator.

color='BLUE' => which means, if this is very few like [blue/yellow], then use this one in the beginning.  because it will do filtering the rows very faster, and then do the search with remaining.

Make sure to place the where condition column which is having very less filtering content should be in the first place.

Coming back to your query, you can have a composite index.  But having 5 rows in the composite index will affect the query performance.  Bit slower for sure.

The `EXPLAIN` plan will help best in your case.